# How to make master node and worker nodes before installing kubernetes on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install kubernetes on my Ubuntu 22.04 os. I found blogs and videos in Youtube but failed and deleted all. I had hard time when making master node and worker nodes because there was no guide for it. So here is my question.

1. Do I have to make VM in computer?
2. How to make master node and worker nodes in linux os?

I had hard time when proper keys were missing but i was able to get over it. But guides were not showing how to make nodes for running kubernetes.